# Pandas aggregate count distinct

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, aggregate

Let's say I have a log of user activity and I want to generate a report of the total duration and the number of unique users per day.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2013-04-01','2013-04-01','2013-04-01','2013-04-02', '2013-04-02'],
    'user_id': ['0001', '0001', '0002', '0002', '0002'],
    'duration': [30, 15, 20, 15, 30]})
```

Aggregating duration is pretty straightforward:

```
group = df.groupby('date')
agg = group.aggregate({'duration': np.sum})
agg
            duration
date
2013-04-01        65
2013-04-02        45
```

What I'd like to do is sum the duration and count distincts at the same time, but I can't seem to find an equivalent for count_distinct:

```
agg = group.aggregate({ 'duration': np.sum, 'user_id': count_distinct})
```

This works, but surely there's a better way, no?

```
group = df.groupby('date')
agg = group.aggregate({'duration': np.sum})
agg['uv'] = df.groupby('date').user_id.nunique()
agg
            duration  uv
date
2013-04-01        65   2
2013-04-02        45   1
```

I'm thinking I just need to provide a function that returns the count of distinct items of a Series object to the aggregate function, but I don't have a lot of exposure to the various libraries at my disposal. Also, it seems that the groupby object already knows this information, so wouldn't I just be duplicating the effort?

Answer (score 223, accepted):

How about either of:

```
>>> df
         date  duration user_id
0  2013-04-01        30    0001
1  2013-04-01        15    0001
2  2013-04-01        20    0002
3  2013-04-02        15    0002
4  2013-04-02        30    0002
>>> df.groupby("date").agg({"duration": np.sum, "user_id": pd.Series.nunique})
            duration  user_id
date                         
2013-04-01        65        2
2013-04-02        45        1
>>> df.groupby("date").agg({"duration": np.sum, "user_id": lambda x: x.nunique()})
            duration  user_id
date                         
2013-04-01        65        2
2013-04-02        45        1
```

Comment: That's it. pd.Series.nunique is what I couldn't find, well, couldn't get to work correctly. Pretty obvious in hindsight. Thanks!

Comment: This answer is outdated. You can now use `nunique` directly. See @Blodwyn Pig's solution below

Comment: Hey do you know how to get non-duplicate count?

Answer (score 118):

'nunique' is an option for [`.agg()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html) since pandas 0.20.0, so:

```
df.groupby('date').agg({'duration': 'sum', 'user_id': 'nunique'})
```

Comment: Is it possible to agg and get the unique values? something  like `duration: np.unique`

Comment: @guy Try `df.groupby('date').agg({'user_id': lambda s: s.unique().reset_index(drop=True)})`

Comment: How do we get the output?

Answer (score 38):

Just adding to the answers already given, the solution using the string `"nunique"` seems much faster, tested here on ~21M rows dataframe, then grouped to ~2M

```
%time _=g.agg({"id": lambda x: x.nunique()})
CPU times: user 3min 3s, sys: 2.94 s, total: 3min 6s
Wall time: 3min 20s

%time _=g.agg({"id": pd.Series.nunique})
CPU times: user 3min 2s, sys: 2.44 s, total: 3min 4s
Wall time: 3min 18s

%time _=g.agg({"id": "nunique"})
CPU times: user 14 s, sys: 4.76 s, total: 18.8 s
Wall time: 24.4 s
```

Comment: Nice catch! I guess it's b/c in a "lambda"/"other function" case it is applied sequentially, while "known" functions are applied to the whole column in a vectorized fashion.

Comment: which solution is from @Blodwyn Pig?

Comment: @Chogg, the fastest one!

Comment: @Chogg - sorry I changed my username.  It was me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get only a number of distinct values per group you can use the method `nunique` directly with the `DataFrameGroupBy` object:

```
df.groupby('date')['user_id'].nunique()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find it for all columns at once with the `aggregate` method,

```
df.aggregate(func=pd.Series.nunique, axis=0)
# or
df.aggregate(func='nunique', axis=0)
```

See [aggregate | Pandas Docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.aggregate.html)