# How to get an indexed DataFrame of value counts where values are datetime strings

Tags: pandas

I have data in a csv file that contains the following fields:

- user_id
- date_created
- date_edited
- date_finalised; and
- date_withdrawn

User_id and date_created fields will never contain null values but the other columns invariably will.

An example:

```
user_id, date_created, date_edited, date_finalised, date_withdrawn
1, 2013-01-31 00:17:01, null, 2013-02-02 14:11:17, null
2, 2013-01-31 01:00:15, 2013-01-31 01:00:30, null, null
```

I would like end up with a DataFrame containing a count of records for each datetime column that occur within certain date period bins i.e. daily, hourly and minutely

Using the example above and daily frequency I would see:

```
date, date_created, date_edited, date_finalised, date_withdrawn
2013-01-31, 2, 1, 0, 0
2013-02-01, 0, 0, 0, 0
2013-02-02, 0, 0, 1, 0
```

After importing the file with

```
data = pd.read_csv('filename.csv')
```

What steps are required to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, ensure that each date column is a datetime64 column (with many rows you should be able to use [parse_dates in the read_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html) but you may have to use [to_datetime](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.tseries.tools.to_datetime.html) and coerce=True):

```
In [11]: df
Out[11]: 
   user_id        date_created         date_edited      date_finalised date_withdrawn
0        1 2013-01-31 00:17:01                 NaT 2013-02-02 14:11:17            NaT
1        2 2013-01-31 01:00:15 2013-01-31 01:00:30                 NaT            NaT
```

Now you can take the [value count for each date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21343401/counting-observations-after-grouping-by-dates-in-pandas/21343850#21343850) e.g. for the date_created column:

```
In [12]: pd.value_counts(pd.DatetimeIndex(df.date_created).normalize())
Out[12]: 
2013-01-31    2
dtype: int64
```

And [concat](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.tools.merge.concat.html) these Series together:

```
In [13]: pd.concat((pd.value_counts(pd.DatetimeIndex(df[col]).normalize()) for col in df.columns if 'date' in col), axis=1).fillna(0)
Out[13]: 
            0  1  2  3
NaT         0  1  1  2
2013-01-31  2  1  0  0
2013-02-02  0  0  1  0
```

*Note: you can `.drop(pd.NaT)` if you don't want this row.*

Unfortunately read_csv's `parse_dates=['date_created', 'date_edited', 'date_finalised', 'date_withdrawn']` doesn't coerce with this small examples (too many nulls), one hack is to use something like:

```
for col in df.columns:
    if 'date' in col:
        df[col] = pd.to_datetime(df[col], coerce=True)
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked a treat :-). I also appreciate the clarity of your answer it helped me _understand_ each stage rather than just replicate it.