# Unmelt Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with two id variables:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,1,1,2,2,3], 
               'num': [10,10,12,13,14,15],
               'q': ['a', 'b', 'd', 'a', 'b', 'z'],
               'v': [2,4,6,8,10,12]})

   id  num  q   v
0   1   10  a   2
1   1   10  b   4
2   1   12  d   6
3   2   13  a   8
4   2   14  b  10
5   3   15  z  12
```

I can pivot the table with:

```
df.pivot('id','q','v')
```

And end up with something close:

```
q    a   b   d   z
id                
1    2   4   6 NaN
2    8  10 NaN NaN
3  NaN NaN NaN  12
```

However, what I really want is (the original unmelted form):

```
id   num   a   b   d   z               
1    10   2   4 NaN NaN
1    12 NaN NaN   6 NaN  
2    13   8 NaN NaN NaN
2    14 NaN  10 NaN NaN
3    15 NaN NaN NaN  12
```

In other words:

1. 'id' and 'num' my indices (normally, I've only seen either 'id' or 'num' being the index but I need both since I'm trying to retrieve the original unmelted form)
2. 'q' are my columns
3. 'v' are my values in the table

**Update**

I found a **close** solution from [Wes McKinney's blog](http://wesmckinney.com/blog/fast-and-easy-pivot-tables-in-pandas-0-5-0/):

```
df.pivot_table(index=['id','num'], columns='q')

         v            
q        a   b   d   z
id num                
1  10    2   4 NaN NaN
   12  NaN NaN   6 NaN
2  13    8 NaN NaN NaN
   14  NaN  10 NaN NaN
3  15  NaN NaN NaN  12
```

However, the format is not quite the same as what I want above.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You're really close slaw.  Just rename your column index to None and you've got what you want.

```
df2 = df.pivot_table(index=['id','num'], columns='q')
df2.columns = df2.columns.droplevel().rename(None)
df2.reset_index().fillna("null").to_csv("test.csv", sep="\t", index=None)
```

**Note** that the the 'v' column is expected to be numeric by default so that it can be aggregated. Otherwise, Pandas will error out with:

```
DataError: No numeric types to aggregate
```

[To resolve this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18554920/pandas-aggregate-count-distinct), you can specify your own aggregation function by using a custom lambda function:

```
df2 = df.pivot_table(index=['id','num'], columns='q', aggfunc= lambda x: x)
```

Comment: Ahhh, I was so close! I knew that it had to do with `df.columns.name` but couldn't figure out how to use `rename` appropriately. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Important note: "close slaw" sounds like "coleslaw".

Answer (score 43):

You could use `set_index` and `unstack`

```
In [18]: df.set_index(['id', 'num', 'q'])['v'].unstack().reset_index()
Out[18]:
q  id  num    a     b    d     z
0   1   10  2.0   4.0  NaN   NaN
1   1   12  NaN   NaN  6.0   NaN
2   2   13  8.0   NaN  NaN   NaN
3   2   14  NaN  10.0  NaN   NaN
4   3   15  NaN   NaN  NaN  12.0
```

Comment: This much cleaner than the accepted answer.  Thanks!

Comment: Thank you. pandas.pivot() with multiple index columns is not as straightforward as I hoped and this solution worked instead.

Comment: pivot_table was converting ints to floats.  This did not do that.  Thanks!

Comment: You can get rid of the "q" with something like this: `del df2.columns.name`.

Answer (score 5):

you can remove name q.

```
df1.columns=df1.columns.tolist()
```

Zero's answer + remove q =

```
df1 = df.set_index(['id', 'num', 'q'])['v'].unstack().reset_index()
df1.columns=df1.columns.tolist()

   id  num    a     b    d     z
0   1   10  2.0   4.0  NaN   NaN
1   1   12  NaN   NaN  6.0   NaN
2   2   13  8.0   NaN  NaN   NaN
3   2   14  NaN  10.0  NaN   NaN
4   3   15  NaN   NaN  NaN  12.0
```

Answer (score 2):

This might work just fine:

1. Pivot

`df2 = (df.pivot_table(index=['id', 'num'], columns='q', values='v')).reset_index())`

2. Concatinate the 1st level column names with the 2nd

`df2.columns =[s1 + str(s2) for (s1,s2) in df2.columns.tolist()]`

Answer (score 1):

Came up with a close solution

```
df2 = df.pivot_table(index=['id','num'], columns='q')
df2.columns = df2.columns.droplevel()
df2.reset_index().fillna("null").to_csv("test.csv", sep="\t", index=None)
```

Still can't figure out how to drop 'q' from the dataframe

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in three steps:

```
#1: Prepare auxilary column 'id_num': 
df['id_num'] = df[['id', 'num']].apply(tuple, axis=1)
df = df.drop(columns=['id', 'num'])

#2: 'pivot' is almost an inverse of melt:
df, df.columns.name = df.pivot(index='id_num', columns='q', values='v').reset_index(), ''

#3: Bring back 'id' and 'num' columns:
df['id'], df['num'] = zip(*df['id_num'])
df = df.drop(columns=['id_num'])
```

This is a result, but with different order of columns:

```
     a     b    d     z  id  num
0  2.0   4.0  NaN   NaN   1   10
1  NaN   NaN  6.0   NaN   1   12
2  8.0   NaN  NaN   NaN   2   13
3  NaN  10.0  NaN   NaN   2   14
4  NaN   NaN  NaN  12.0   3   15
```

Alternatively with proper order:

```
def multiindex_pivot(df, columns=None, values=None):
    #inspired by: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/23955
    names = list(df.index.names)
    df = df.reset_index()
    list_index = df[names].values
    tuples_index = [tuple(i) for i in list_index] # hashable
    df = df.assign(tuples_index=tuples_index)
    df = df.pivot(index="tuples_index", columns=columns, values=values)
    tuples_index = df.index  # reduced
    index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples_index, names=names)
    df.index = index
    df = df.reset_index() #me
    df.columns.name = ''  #me
    return df

df = df.set_index(['id', 'num'])
df = multiindex_pivot(df, columns='q', values='v')
```