# how to transform dataframe so that column values are row values

Tags: python, pandas, melt

I have the following dataframe, which looks like the below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'fruit': ['berries','berries', 'berries', 'tropical', 
'tropical','tropical','berries','nuts'], 
           'code': [100,100,100,200,200, 300,400,500],
           'subcode': ['100A', '100B', '100C','200A', '200B','300A', 
           '400A', '500A']})


    code    fruit   subcode
  0 100     berries 100A
  1 100     berries 100B
  2 100     berries 100C
  3 200     tropica 200A
  4 200     tropical 200B
  5 300     tropical 300A
  6 400     berries 400A
  7 500     nuts    500A
```

I want to transform the dataframe to this format:

```
    code    fruit   subcode1 subcode1 subcode1
  0 100     berries 100A      100B   100C
  3 200     tropica 200A      200B
  5 300     tropical 300A
  6 400     berries 400A
  7 500     nuts    500A
```

Unfortunately, I'm stuck as to how to proceed. I've consulted posts like, [Unmelt Pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31306741/unmelt-pandas-dataframe), and have combinations of stack and unstack. I suspect that some concatenation is involved, too. Would appreciate any advice to help point me in the right direction!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `groupby`, take the values and convert them to series.

```
df.groupby(['code','fruit'])['subcode'].apply(
         lambda x: x.values
      ).apply(pd.Series)
       .add_prefix('subcode_')

                subcode_0 subcode_1 subcode_2
code fruit                                 
100  berries       100A      100B      100C
200  tropical      200A      200B       NaN
300  tropical      300A       NaN       NaN
400  berries       400A       NaN       NaN
500  nuts          500A       NaN       NaN
```

Comment: I like this approach, but I dislike the apply(Series). Good effort though!

Comment: I doo agreee, consumes a lotta time.

Comment: Is there any difference between applying ravel versus list?

Comment: @ALollz I just realize that's unnecessary .

Comment: thanks so much! this totally works on my data set and i learned that there is an .add_prefix/sufix to row/col labels.

Answer (score 4):

Play around a bit with `set_index` and `unstack`, and you'll get it.

```
(df.set_index(['code', 'fruit'])
   .set_index(df.subcode.str.extract('([a-zA-Z]+)', expand=False), append=True)
   .subcode
   .unstack()
   .fillna('')                  # these last three 
   .reset_index()               # operations are  
   .rename_axis(None, axis=1)   # not important
)

   code     fruit     A     B     C
0   100   berries  100A  100B  100C
1   200  tropical  200A  200B      
2   300  tropical  300A            
3   400   berries  400A            
4   500      nuts  500A
```

Answer (score 3):

With `defaultdict`

```
from collections import defaultdict


d = defaultdict(list)

for f, c, s in df.itertuples(index=False):
    d[(f, c)].append(s)

pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
    {k: dict(enumerate(v)) for k, v in d.items()}, orient='index'
).add_prefix('subcode').rename_axis(['fruit', 'code']).reset_index()

      fruit  code subcode0 subcode1 subcode2
0   berries   100     100A     100B     100C
1   berries   400     400A      NaN      NaN
2      nuts   500     500A      NaN      NaN
3  tropical   200     200A     200B      NaN
4  tropical   300     300A      NaN      NaN
```

Comment: thanks! I'll will have to read up on default dict to see how it works. definitely appreciate learning different approaches.