# Is there a list of Pandas groupby-agg named functions?

Tags: python, pandas

From answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18554920/pandas-aggregate-count-distinct), there are named functions for .agg that are optimized to perform much faster than the equivalent numpy or custom lambda function.

However, I can't find a comprehensive list of these--for example, I only learned that "nunique" exists from quora.

In the documentation, these are called [Cython optimized functions](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#cython-optimized-aggregation-functions).

Comment: Check here: https://www.shanelynn.ie/summarising-aggregation-and-grouping-data-in-python-pandas/

Comment: I do see nunique as an option, but not really a table of all the aggregate functions. Since the string versions are so much faster, it'd be good to have a list of all available ones so we can use that one instead of the lambda versions.