# How to filter a Pandas DataFrame to contain only unique values in one column and aggregate over other columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame like below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": ["apple", "apple", "banana", "banana", "banana", "pineapple"],
                   "B": [0.5, 0.77, 0.32, 0.16, 0.05, 1],
                   "C": [132, 44, 32, 11, 0, 5]})
```

Now, I want to create a DataFrame from this in which I want to keep, for each unique value of column `A`, only the row with the highest value of column `B` and throw away the other rows. The desired result would look like this:

```
A            B        C
apple        0.77     44
banana       0.32     32
pineapple    1        5
```

Is there an elegant, Python efficient way of doing this? (The real DataFrame is quit big and has more extra columns besides `C`)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas aggregate count distinct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18554920/pandas-aggregate-count-distinct)

Comment: `df.sort_values('B').drop_duplicates('A',keep='last')`

Comment: No it does not unfortunately. I have lots of columns that I want to keep the same, I just basically want to look at groups of unique values for column A, and keep only 1 row and throw away the others

Answer (score 2):

Try `groupby().idxmax()`:

```
df.loc[df.groupby('A')['B'].idxmax()]
```

Or `drop_duplicates` on sorted dataframe:

```
df.sort_values('B').drop_duplicates('A', keep='last')
```